# How to install previous version of xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

In AppStore is available Xcode 4.4 but I need Xcode 4.2 and I can't find it at all. Help me please. Where can I find it and install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode is available from the [Apple's developer support center](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/).  You'll need an account but they are free.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this because I've never used Mac OS at all